# Java async rest call in a loop

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a rest service returning the name of the customer and I want to make an async call to retrieve the name of a list of customers.

So I have a list of customers and currently I'm iterating the list and making the call one by one:

```
 public List<Participant> retrieveParticipantsFullName(List<Participant> participantList) throws GeneralException {

    for (Participant participant : participantList) {
        String fullRetrievePartFullURL = retrieveParticipantsFullNameUrl+participant.getCustomerType()+"/"+participant.getCustomerID();
        ResponseEntity<RetrieveCustomerNameResponse> resultResp ;

            resultResp =  restTemplate.getForEntity(fullRetrievePartFullURL,
                    RetrieveCustomerNameResponse.class);
            participant.setCustomerMiddlename(resultResp.getBody().getCustomerNameOut().getCustomerMiddlename());
    }

    return participantList;
```

Is there any way to make this call in an async way so it can be executed in paralled?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of using the `RestTemplate`, you need to use the `AsyncRestTemplate`, which returns `ListenableFuture`s.

Comment: can you please share your source code ?